# Indian tamil font cross browser font size issue

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts, cross-browser

[image]I am working on the site https//:www.femina.in/tamil/index.php

But the issue is font size different in chrome and mozilla. Also in IE and safari.. May i know what will be the solution.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here using the stack snippet: `<>` in the editor. A link to a site that may change at any time is useless to future visitors

Comment: the problem is i could not detect exactly where the issue exist... how can i post all code like css/html and tags

Comment: In my Chrome and Firefox on OSX the pages are identical. Please check your zoom level

Comment: plz check attachment. i have check zoom level.. i have also use css media query to detect mozilla browser.(as of now the css code is disabled) but the solution is working perfect on my machine, not all machines... i suspect this is DPI issue..

Comment: I cannot recreate

Comment: If you don't know where the problem is exactly, what you should to is remove things (links, scripts etc) from the page one by one until the problem goes away. If the problem doesn't go away, then at the end you'll be left with a [mcve].

Comment: Anyway, to get you started, which font are you using? Is it a webfont and can all browsers read it? Oh, and don't use SVG for a font format.

Comment: For Femina.in/hindi we have not used any additional language based font. .. it's also native language.. then why the problem occurs for another indian language... we use same font for all version of fenina.in .. for that particular website.. i temporarily use ""arial

Comment: Hi I have found solution. . We have added particular webfonts to websites. . Ty all

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found solution. . We have added particular unique one webfonts to websites. . Ty all